# Error in setup upgrade and static content deploy

Tags: error, deploy

I repeatedly getting the following error while I try to execute

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

or

```
php -d set_time_limit=3600 -d memory_limit=1024M bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think di folder are generate at compile time inside var folder.

> delete var/di and var/generation
>
> delete pub/static/* keep .htaccess file only.

if di folder is not available first create di folder inside var folder.

**Run command :**

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Answer (score 0):

For Static content deploy quick solution add memory size in the command like:

> php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

change 6G to what you want